# Can I change architecture from 32 to 64bits without using a CD?

Tags: installation, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to “upgrade” from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

I accidentally installed the wrong architecture and would like to "upgrade" to amd64.
Is there anyway, without downloading the am64 ISO and burning it.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You cant just say to the package manager that you will now be using 64bit instead of 32bit, that is not the way we roll.

You will need to download the CD and install your system again, probably you can keep the settings and files for your user's home and your `/etc` folder.

For more information on that please visit the follow similar posts:

- [How do I upgrade from x86 to x64 without losing settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6176/how-do-i-upgrade-from-x86-to-x64-without-losing-settings)
- [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

Comment: You might want to move this to the original question.