# Upgrade from 32bit to 64bit?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to “upgrade” from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

I've got a pc with a 64-bit processor but somehow got stuck on the 32-bit version of 11.10. Is there some way to switch to 64-bit without having to back everything up and do a clean install?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/5018/18612