# How to upgrade from 32bit Wubi to 64bit Wubi?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, wubi, 32-bit

I have a 12.04 beta 2 Wubi installed. I want to change it to a 64 bit wubi when I upgrade to the final 12.04 version.

1. Would I need to uninstall the old Wubi and then reinstall a complete new one?
2. When I download the wubi, it does not say if it's 32 or 64 bit. So how do I upgrade/reinstall to wubi 64 bit?

My system is Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 540 @ 2.53GHz × 4. It has 4 GB of RAM. So, I guess it's capable of running a 64-bit OS.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot change architecture 32 to 64 without a clean install. Upgrading 32 bit stable you just need to usual update. Nothing special is needed.

Comment: Thanks! What about using a wubi for 64 bit? how do i do that? when i download the wubi installer it does not say whether its 32 or 64..

Comment: wubi should automatically detect your architecture and if you have a 64 bit processor, install 64 bit Ubuntu. Are you sure you are running a 32 bit version of Ubuntu ? Output of `uname -r`Although you will get various opinions, IMO if you have decided to stay with Ubuntu, why not do a standard installation ? IMO a standard install is easier to maintain ;)

Comment: @NewUbuntuUser is your windows 64bit? if so I think you dont need to care about wubi details.  Just 64 bit ubuntu and install over wubi. You may need to change VT option enabled in the BIOS. I am not sure though

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Ya im sure its a 32 bit version uname -r gave this result 3.2.0-24-generic-pae , dunno what it actually means :)

Comment: @kindahero the windows i am running is 32 bit,I tried running the wubi.exe from the downloaded 700mb iso file but it would not let me install wubi , i guess i would need to uninstall the previous version first. Well ill try after a couple of days , today the download speed is pathetic 20kbps Thanks!

Comment: @NewUbuntuUser Best part of living in Japan is you can download ubuntu iso in 3min on release day. good luck with installation. as bodhi.zazen said you can take full control of your system if you go for duel boot

Comment: @kindahero Thanks Dude!! n have fun.. well i love working on ubuntu  32 so thought that 64 would be better !! ;) My HDD is already partitioned in 4 drives and I cant do any more new partitions that's why i'm stuck with the WUBi