# Can I upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, multiarch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to “upgrade” from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

There was a similar question for older Ubuntu versions, but not for 12.04.

Multiarch is ready now and in Ubuntu 12.04?

Can I upgrade from 32 bit to 64 bit?

Comment: No you can not. Because most of the 32 bit apps will not work in 64bit, need to install all lib (removing 32bit lib) for 64bit. So it's similar to install a new system :)

Comment: If someone has an answer addressing 12.04 in a more specific way (read as it just works) than was already stated in the other question, please add it as a new answer specific to 12.04.  My close vote is based on the fact that we should have one question on the topic with diverse and good answers.

Comment: Also related: [How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one)