# error: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)

Tags: wireless, system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 and by the way my wireless is not working. So, I'm trying to fix this problem manually. I have installed the 64 bit Ubuntu already. The problem is I cannot install any packages because when I do I get an error. For example
if I run the command

```
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb
```

I get this error:

> ```
> dpkg: error processing wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb (--install: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)
> ```

I also get this error if I try to install any other package. My system is a Dell 3421 which has an i5 processor so I don't know why Ubuntu think I have a i386 system. If I run the `uname` command I get these results:

```
uname -i 
i686

uname -p
i686

uname-m
i686
```

Comment: what is the output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: Linux my6543-Inspiron-3421 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue OCT 9 19:32:08 UT C 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 17):

The answer lies hidden in the documentation of `dpkg`:

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

will show you the architecture `dpkg` is willing to install packages for.

If the architecture **amd64** is not listed, an amd package will be refused, even if all else seems fine. Now you can try to add it with the following command:

```
dpkg --add-architecture amd64
```

and show it by using the command:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

On a system that was clearly installed as amd64, I had success in making dpkg trying to install the package. Of course further problems may be detected, such as failed dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

The different variants of `uname` gives an indication of the kernel that you have installed.

This in turn gives a clue as to the version of Ubuntu you have installed as well as the explanation of your error

> error: package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386)

On a 64bit install you would expect something like:

```
Linux emachine 3.5.0-26-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 11 22:17:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The key part is `x86_64` which indicates a 64bit installation.

Your output - `i686` indicates that you have installed a 32bit version of Ubuntu.

Some useful links at the end - suffice to say - you cannot install a 64bit debian package on a 32bit system.  That is what your error message is basically informing you.

You'll need the 32bit variant of the package - it usually ends with the name `i386.deb`.

---

#### Useful links:

- [Difference between the i386 download and the amd64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54296/difference-between-the-i386-download-and-the-amd64?rq=1)
- [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)
- [How do I check if I have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os)

Comment: I double checked and you are right. I downloaded and installed the i386 version. Thanks a lot.