# Ubuntu 32 to 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I've installed ubuntu 12.04 in a dual boot with a windows 7.
I've got the ISO months ago to use in another pc (32bit). Now I've got an laptop with windows 7 64-bit, and installed the 32-bit ubuntu. How to proceed, if I want to use a 64-bit version of Ubuntu?
Ps: I'm newbie in any Linux OS and in english language.
Thanks

Comment: download the 64-bit version and re-install.

Answer (score 2):

The 32-bit and 64-bit ISOs are separate.  You'll have to download the 64-bit ISO if you want to run 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

You can find it here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: So I need to unistall my current version?

Comment: That is going to be the easiest way, yes.  According to this answer (http://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation) it's not impossible to do, but it is definitely easier to just re-install.

Comment: You do not "uninstall", you simply re-install. The 64 bit install should preserver your data in /home, but I advise you back up any data you wish to keep just in case.