# 32-bit to 64-bit migration using virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, 32-bit

I have a 32-bit Ubuntu installation which I would like to migrate to 64-bit. To minimize risk and to ensure that the installation is working I would like to first do the install on a virtualbox VM.

I intend to install a fresh copy of 64-bit Ubuntu on virtualbox. Get a list of packages on the 32-bit system. Install them on the 64-bit. Merge my /etc using some kind of interactive merge. Then mount my home directory, make sure everything is working. Backup my old root and then copy my new root from VM to host.

Does this plan look okay? Is there something easier?

Comment: related: [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](http://askubuntu.com/q/5018)

Answer (score 0):

The method you came up with may work, but it would be far easier to:

1. Export the list of packages on your 32-bit system
2. Install Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit straight over the old installation, selecting the otion during setup to keep the data in your /home partition
3. Import the list of packages to your 64 bit system

Comment: I'm afraid of having a broken installation during the transition.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your current 32-bit installation, run the command:

   $ dpkg --get-selections > ~/32bit-packages
2. Install Ubuntu 64-bit
3. On the new 64-bit installation, run the command:

   $ sudo dpkg --set-selections < 32bit-packages
   $ sudo apt-get -y update
   $ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade