# Installed 32 bit

Tags: 32-bit

so I am kind of new to the UBuntu thing and I installed 32 bit instead of 64 bit  ( my pc has 8gb of ram , but did not realize that at the time) . My question is should I re-install the 64-bit or live it like this?

Comment: Well, I can only say what I would do: reinstall, since you (I guess) just installed it, and it is a waste to spill a lot of memory :)

Comment: Yep, reinstall it!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have done a bunch of work to it already; I would suggest a clean install.

[Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

EDIT: If your hardware is new, go for 64bit.  Otherwise use 32bit PAE.

32bit/32bit PAE/64bit comparison:

http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-decide-if-you-should-use-32bit-or-64bit-ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.