# How to install Sage on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, sagemath

So I was following the instructions here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SAGE

- The apt get command on your link doesn't find anything.
- And what is this instruction of putting a link to the "sage executable in /usr/local/bin"

So in my current folder structure I find, `~/Desktop/sage/sage-6.4-x86_64-Linux/src/sage`

Is this the "sage executable"?

Guessing so, I did this (as per the above link)

```
ln -s ~/Desktop/sage/sage-6.4-x86_64-Linux/src/sage /usr/local/bin/sage
```

But then doing the above yields a link to this in /usr/local/bin called "sage".

But that link doesn't work.

(the sub-folder "sage" of Desktop is something that I created into which I unzipped the file I downloaded from the mirror - the downloaded folder called itself by that name, "sage-6.4-x86_64-Linux" and its subfolders are what it anyway came with)

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Yes - anyway I can confirm?

Comment: It said "trusty". I think I am on "14.04 LTS"

Comment: Excellent. You can use the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~aims/+archive/ubuntu/sagemath

Comment: @muru that is the first step in his link...

Comment: Okay - so I have to just run those 3 commands one after another? - and nothing else? - how do i run sage after that?

Comment: @Anirbit Since you already ran those commands, are you on a 32-bit system? What does `uname -m` say?

Comment: @muru I get the same errors as before after the last step, "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sagemath-upstream-binary is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'sagemath-upstream-binary' has no installation candidate
"

Comment: @muru uname -m says "i686"

Comment: @Anirbit there's the problem. You're trying to run 64-bit binaries on 32-bit Ubuntu, and the PPA only supports 64-bit. Download the 32-bit binaries. Or install 64-bit Ubuntu. There's no reason not to use 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: @muru How do I upgrade to a 64-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: @Anirbit it's possible but very risky: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation. It's simpler to do a fresh install.

Comment: @muru Any way to do a fresh install online?

Comment: @Anirbit I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @muru Can you explain how to do a fresh install? Like can I avoid having to burn a new disk? Are there versions of sage which work on 32 bit?

Comment: @Anirbit Yes, you can use 32-bit Sage. The files will have `i686` in the name instead of `x86_64`.

Comment: @muru And from where do I install that? And how can I do a fresh install of a 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: @muru Is there some "sudo -apt get " styled installation method that will get me a 32-bit sage running for now?

Comment: @Anirbit nope. You can download 32-bit the same way you downloaded 64-bit Sage, but look i686 links.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to getting it wrong, there isn't anything for you to miss, but here go some insights into each step:

```
apt-add-repository -y ppa:aims/sagemath
```

this add the APT to your repository, in other words it adds this location for you APT look for when trying to install new packages. It should ask for some kind of confirmation regarding the gpu key, accept it and it will add it.

```
apt-get update
```

This updates your local listing of packages tough re-downloading every packaging list you has, all the ubuntu's defaults and also the sage listings

```
apt-get install sagemath-upstream-binary
```

This one is the one who really installs sage. What is wrong?

Comment: While it was necessary in 2014 to add a PPA, installing Sage Math no longer requires this, and you can just write `apt-get install sagemath` in a standard Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked in 2014, Sage Math has become a part of the standard Ubuntu distribution:

```
sudo apt install sagemath
```

So you don't need to add any PPAs at this point.

Comment: FYI, `apt install` works nowadays, and has a colorful interface. `apt-get install` still works, though.

Answer (score 0):

To allow sage to work in bash, you need to install realpath:

```
sudo apt-get install realpath
```

Assuming your link is to the executable, and that /usr/local/bin is in your PATH variable, you should be able to run sage by just typing sage in a terminal.