# DEB file not installing, wrong architecture?

Tags: software-installation, deb, architecture

I just tried to install a program from Atom.IO, it's a really nice coding text editor. However, when I open the .deb file, it opens the software center and throws the error "Wrong architecture 'amd64'". I'm not sure what that means. Should I look for some alternative, or should I try the provided archive file instead?

Note that this is my first time using Ubuntu, or any form of linux other than Android, so I don't know much.

Comment: Why not search for the right version of the program in the Ubuntu repos, or a PPA, or the source code & build it yourself? Why re-install your whole OS because you downloaded one wrong file?

Comment: Its a beta test, its not on the store yet I think. Besides, I'm just using it until I have a chance to send the PC to a shop to see why a Windows driver stopped working. (No internet, something about a blank IPConfig, I dunno but I was told to try a new OS. It works, but I have expensive Windows software so it's temporary. I may rig a dual boot tho, I love this)

Comment: Ah, ok. There's also the "persistent" option too for running only from a live usb, it stores OS changes to a file on the usb (or even a different partition of the usb for more space, might possibly work with a HD partition too, maybe). Then you wouldn't need to install Ubuntu to the hard drive at all. FYI, I run live all the time without persistence, just saving config files occasinally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrong architecture refers to the type of processor your device is using.

You have downloaded a deb file designed for a processor running the amd64 machine language, commonly referred to as a 64bit processor or an x86_64 processor.

But either the processor you are using is not a 64 bit processor, or you have installed a version of Ubuntu not designed for 64 bit.

How old is this computer? If it is more then 5 years old, it may be a 32 bit processor, in which case you need the i386 package (or i486 or i686 or x86, depending on site notation, for most purposes, it's the same thing).

Is it a micro-device, like a beaglebone? It may be using an ARMv7 architecture.

Is it a chinese system, like a Lemote Yeelong? It may be using a MIPS architecture.

If you are certain it is an x86_64 processor, check to make sure you haven't installed the 32 bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay then. I don't know where "about this PC" is in Ubuntu, but I do know that it's main OS is Win8 64 bit... Hmm, how do I find out if I'm using Ubuntu 32 bit, and what do I download to swap it?

Comment: Click the little cog logo in the top right of the screen, and select "about this computer". What does it say under overview->os type?

Comment: Apparently I have Ubuntu 32 bit... Darn it, just after I set up shop and everything... Wait wouldn't a 32b app break on a 64b processor? Either way, I know what to fix now. Thanks

Comment: x86_64 (64bit) is an extension/update of x86 (usually called "32 bit"). 32bit code doesn't automagically work on 64bit software, but since 32 bit on 64 bit compatibility is a feature of every major OS, I guess it's not hard. Unfortunately, it doesn't go the other way. Unfortunately, it seems the best way to move from 32 to 64 bit is to [burn everything to the ground and start again](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation).

Comment: Well, at least its a Live Drive and not my primary OS...