# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) to latest Ubuntu Budgie (64-bit)?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit) is installed on my laptop along with Windows 7. I have barely used Ubuntu, but I'm on it now since Windows is troubling me.

I was looking for a Ubuntu flavour that is light-weight, and I found Ubuntu Budgie, which is also pretty sweet looking, hence I opted for that.

I'd be highly grateful for exact steps on how I can update to the latest version of Ubuntu Budgie (64-bit version.)

Please let me know if I need to update Ubuntu 14.04 as well.

**Note**: When I was trying to update the OS using Software Updater, I would get the error, "Requires installing from untrusted sources." And I'd have two options, "Settings..." [which leads to the Software Updater] and "Close".

Related Queries:

- Do all the flavours of Ubuntu require the 'original' Ubuntu to be installed, or they are stand-alone operating systems?
- I need an operating system which is light-weight and can run most Windows software. Is Ubuntu Budgie a good pick or should I go for something else?

Device specifications:

- Memory: 3.9 GiB
- Processor: Intel Core i3-2350M @ 2.30GHz x 4
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NVD9
- OS type: 32 bit
- Disk: 47.3 GB

Comment: You can *upgrade via re-install* which allows you to skip releases... but 14.04 to 20.04 is a big jump, so unless you do some homework, problems could be expected...   *upgrade via re-install* allows you to also move from *i386* (32-bit) to *amd64* (64-bit) as all system directories are wiped, prior to install, system installed, then your old-packages are re-install (if available for new release; here the big jump in releases maybe an issue!) as long as you don't format... but it's an option; otherwise look at @ChanganAuto's comments..  Budgie is not the lightest of desktops

Comment: Alright, @guiverc. Understood.

Comment: @karel Thank you for sharing the article. I believe it would help the coming viewers. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no upgrade possible from 32-bit to 64-bit.

There's no upgrade possible from Ubuntu to Ubuntu-Budgie. It's possible turn standard Ubuntu into something Ubuntu-Budgie look-alike but it's moot for this question.

And even if the original 14.04 was 64-bit thus having a possible upgrade path to Ubuntu 20.04 - 14.04 (EoL) -> 16.04 (about to be EoL) -> 18.04 -> 20.04 - failure is expected and it would take days to complete therefore such process is strongly discouraged.

**Conclusion**: Backup personal files and install Ubuntu-Budgie 64-bit

Comment: Alright, got that. So you're also suggesting a fresh install just like kleinbottle4. Could you please let me know how I can install Ubuntu-Budgie 64-bit, and how do I get rid of the currently installed OS. (I would like to keep Windows 7 tho'.)

Comment: Keeping any unsupported OS like Windows 7, if you're using it online, is the single most dumb thing (and dangerous for you and everybody else) you can do with a computer. The same, of course, goes for using 14.04 (EoL since 2019!). You can install the new OS by re-using the previous partitions though but, if it isn't clear enough by now, I'm strongly suggesting the "Erase and install..." option (nukes both obsolete OSes).

Comment: Alright buddy, got that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did:

- Removed partition for Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit).
- Removed GRUB bootloader using Easy BCD.
- Installed Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (64-bit) on dual boot.

Its installation time was 7 minutes. It's very lightweight comparatively. It's got some of its other issues, but hey, speed is what matters more. I guess it consumes more power. But my laptop's got 50 minutes on Windows 7. 40 minutes on Lubuntu is a big difference, but not as bad.

Regarding the other part of the question, try visiting the link suggested by [@karel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation):

[Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

Comment: FYI:  You didn't need to remove the 14.04 partition; as you can have installed into it (Lubuntu test for that as it's a *Replace a partition* option). You can look for solutions on reducing power (Linux defaults to *speed* not power conservation)

Comment: Okay. Yes, I remember seeing the option to replace partitions. But I had already formatted the required partition using Windows. And, I was unaware the Linux defaults to speed. Thank you for educating. I tried looking for the power consumption-thing once, in a hurry. I have been procrastinating to look for solutions ever since. I'll try looking for it now.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to get a Live USB from the Ubuntu website and do a fresh install. (Back up your files!)

Comment: Okay. Do I need to remove the currently installed OS for that? If yes, how?

Comment: The new install of 18.04 or 20.04 your choice will replace the old long past support 14.04

Comment: @David I wish I had seen this comment earlier. :D